# Finding duplicate rows from a tab delimited text file

Tags: excel, text

Need help with removing duplicate rows from a text file which has data in the following format

Sample tab de-limted text file - streets.txt

```
row0 street zipcode city state country
row1 5th-Ave 1111 Chicago Illinois USA
row2 3rd-street 1111 Chicago Illinois USA
row4 3rd-street 1111 Chicago Illinois USA
row5 10th-Ave 2222 Carlsbad California USA
row6 10th-Ave 2222 Carlsbad California USA
```

Is there an quick  way to

1) Get an output which contains duplicate rows into a new file ( row 3 and row 6 in the example)

Desired output of duplicates.txt

```
row0 3rd-street 1111 Chicago Illinois USA
row6 10th-Ave 2222 Carlsbad California USA
```

2) Remove the duplicate rows ( version of the original file removing row 3 and 6 into a new file)

Desired output of duplicates_removed.txt

```
row0 street zipcode city state country
row1 5th-Ave 1111 Chicago Illinois USA
row2 3rd-street 1111 Chicago Illinois USA
row3 10th-Ave 2222 Carlsbad California USA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you're in Excel, one way would be to simply create an additional column that contains all of the items from all of the other columns. Sort by that column and you can easily identify the identical rows and handle them by hand.

Assuming that your 6 columns are in A-F, in G1 put

```
  =A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 & E1 & F1
```

Copy that down your list. Then sort by G1, then by A1. This will put the first of identical rows as the first in the list (i.e., row2 will be before row4)

Then in H2 put the following formula:

```
  =if(G2=G1,"duplicate","")
```

Copy that down your list. Now copy columns G and H and use Paste Special / Values. Sort by H, then by A. This will give you all of the first entries of each duplicate group (including the completely unique values) in a group at the beginning and then will sort all second and subsequent duplicates at the end. Cut-and-paste the second group to another sheet. Save each sheet as a separate tab-delimited file.

Converting this procedure to VBA code should be self-evident.

Answer (score 0):

1. sort all the lines.
2. go over the lines and delete each line that is equal to the last line you checked.

This can be done in many scripting languages including Python. To do that in excel - you will have to copy each line that is different from the line above it to a different sheet, after sorting.

Answer (score 0):

if you open this in excel, and all of the data per row is in 1 cell each then there is a filter that will remove duplicates.

select col A with all the data, then goto Filter>advanced> "unique records only". Then you can just copy pasta col A to a new sheet.